# D3 circles too big after reappearing

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a D3 map of the United States with circles drawn on top. When I resize the window, the map disappears and a D3 bar chart appears.

When I refresh the page and start with the chart then change to the map, the circles appear huge. 
[image: Circles too big after resizing from small to large window.]

I also notice the state border lines are thicker as well.

I built the map and bar chart within two functions: `map()` and `mobileChart()`. Both are executed at the bottom of my script.

Here's what my code looks like to draw the circles:

```
map
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "bubbles")
    .attr("cx", coordinates[0])
    .attr("cy", coordinates[1])
    .attr("r", function(){
             return radius(d[i].total)
    )};
```

`coordinates` are my circles' latitudes and longitudes, which are read from a csv file. `r` is determined by a total number from the same file.

It seems the code is re-entering the numbers to determine the circles' sizes and locations several times after the map reappears.

This doesn't happen when I start the page with the map first. When I resize from map to chart to map again, the circles stay the same.

I use the following function to change the size of the map based on the window's size. Perhaps this is where my solution comes from?

```
d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);
function resize() {
    // Adjust things when the window size changes
    width = parseInt(d3.select('#map').style('width'));
    width = width - margin.left - margin.right;
    height = width * mapRatio;

    // Update projection
    projection
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
        .scale(width);

    // Resize the map container
    map
        .style('width', width + 'px')
        .style('height', height + 'px')
}
```

Comment: Can you build a http://plnkr.co/ of this?  It's difficult to follow your question.  Also, what is the definition of the function `radius`, that seems to be the heart of this question.

Comment: Here's a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/rntwBPf7dKeueqttcTI3

I threw it together quickly, but the problem is there. What's going on is the bubbles (and the map in the plnkr) don't appear correctly when it is hidden and then appears using jQuery.

Comment: I still don't understand the workflow.  In the plnkr, no mater what kind of re-sizing, show/hiding I do the circles seem to scale with the map.

Comment: Hm. Try scrunching the window to <400px, so the map disappears. Then load the page. My problem comes from when the map is hidden at page start. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. If that doesn't work, I'll make a gif of the issue.

Comment: Here's the gif: http://imgur.com/yWCyCKg. The first part goes from the map to the bar chart. The quick blink in the middle is me refreshing the page then going from the chart to map, which shows the bubbles blowing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took another look at this question and I finally think I know what you are asking.  Essentially it boils down to you set your circle radius to a fixed value regardless of the width of the container.  Since you are using a `viewBox` on your SVG a small container scales the radius up dramatically.  If you start with a huge width and size down the reverse happens and the circles are tiny.

The easy fix it to just scale the radius against the width:

```
d3.csv("pickups.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    total: +d.total,
    coordinates: projection([d.lat, d.lon])
  };
}, function(error, rows) {

  map.append("g")
    .selectAll(".bubbles")
    .data(rows)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "bubbles")
      .attr("cx", function(d){
        if (d.coordinates)
          return d.coordinates[0];
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d){
        if (d.coordinates)
          return d.coordinates[1];
      })
      .attr("r", function(d){
          return radius(d.total) * (width/goodCircleWidth) //<-- THIS ADDED
      });
});
```

As you see above, I am scaling the radius against a known width "goodCircleWidth" (where you think they look good).

Also note, a point on `d3.js` coding conventions.  Instead of explicitly looping your pickups data, it's preferable to data-bind it like I've done above.

Here's an updated [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/LFKLJLNJKGQFQEEaqjPI?p=preview).

Comment: You are awesome. This fixed it. And thanks for the data bind tip. I always used a loop, but your suggestion definitely makes things easier.